# Can't install tern.java in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to install tern.java 1.2.0 for Eclipse IDE 4.5.2 for Java developers, the installation starts but then stops just one quarter of the way through with an error whose details are as follows:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Unable to read repository at http://oss.opensagres.fr/tern.repository/1.2.0/plugins/ternjs_1.2.0.201606160856.jar.
>   Connection reset

However, when I go to the url indicated in the error and omit the "." at the end, I can download the jar file, but, not when I leave the period at end (right after the word "jar") as then I get 404 error. Apparently, the installation program is having the same issue. So, then, the question is where do I put this jar file so that the tern.java gets properly installed in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so finally figured how to do it. The issue is that server that the url mentioned in the error points to just times out. Alternatively, I downloaded the zipped version of the application and then installed it in Eclipse as a software.